# Azure cloud. One database per (asp.net registered) client

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure

Good morning,

I am using an asp.net framework with an azure client database.

I am now creating another server on Azure to host databases. On this server, for each customer registering on the website (for which 1 entry is created in my first database), I need to create a database with 8 tables - identical for each customer.

What would be the best thing to map the ASP.NET ID to a new database? Which framework would you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: A new database on your own [azure-]server or a new azure sql database? The first option wouldn't scale very well.

Comment: Yes @HenkHolterman you are of course right. That would be a disaster. However, I am currently looking into Rob 's answer down here as well; time to do my homework on it

Comment: Yes, these elastic pools can be used for many 1000s of Dbs. There are some intermediate levels too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than running a VM where you're going to have to manage a SQL Server installation and write a bunch of code to handle a database per tenant scenario, I highly, highly, highly recommend taking a look at Azure SQL's multi-tenant sharding support. All of this code is already written for you. And it's not that you're paying for one DB per client - check out elastic pooling.

You can read the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction).

Also note, this option will scale very well.

I have done this three different ways: a database per client where I wrote my own code to manage sharding, a single database with a separate schema per client (a huge pain in the rear), and using Azure SQL sharding support. It's not just the issue of correctly separating client data. You also need to think about querying for reporting across all client databases, and managing schema changes. Under the first two options, if you change a schema, you get to modify N client databases. Azure SQL's sharding tools will manage this for you.

Comment: Rob, many thanks for your comment.
I will read through it and update my post above for future readers once I will know more about it. I am sorry about the lack of detail in my question, but I wanted to see what other people would think.